# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pyspark does not support any application options

Tags: pyspark

When configure jupyter notebook in pyspark, it has something wrong:
in the .bashrc file:

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --ip=my ip"
```

when I input pyspark, it shows `[C 13:51:52.029 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.`

and I use `pyspark --allow-root`, but it shows :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pyspark does not support any application options.
at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildPySparkShellCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:290)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:147)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your .bashrc file as:

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --ip=my ip --allow-root"
```